# Restsharp return null when Response have location header only, no body

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, response, restsharp

i am using RestSharp to consume the CapsuleCRM API.

When you POST to create an entity, the API does not return anything in the body of the response, only a location header to the newly created row.

Like so:

http://developer.capsulecrm.com/v1/writing/

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: https://sample.capsulecrm.com/api/party/1000
```

So, if RestSharp is to be able to return an object, it must follow that location header url, and retrieve the new object from there, but this does not seem to be happening.

This questions is similar to a different question, but not a duplicate:
[RestSharp returns null value when response header has location field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723099/restsharp-returns-null-value-when-response-header-has-location-field)

**Update:**
I have posted a hacky solution I came up with as an answer, but is there really no way for RestSharp to handle this by default?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not an update to your question. If you still want a better answer, leave your question open and people will provide one if they have one. Please also share sample code for both your question and solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by making a tweaked version of the

```
public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
```

method, but it really feels like there should be a better solution to this.

Source code at:
https://github.com/bjovas/CapsuleDotNet/blob/master/src/CapsuleDotNetWrapper/CapsuleApi.cs

```
    public T CreateExecute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_authtoken, "x");

        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);


        string locationUrl = (string)response.Headers.Where(h => h.Type == ParameterType.HttpHeader && h.Name == "Location").SingleOrDefault().Value;
        int id;
        if (int.TryParse(locationUrl.Remove(0, string.Format("{0}{1}", client.BaseUrl, request.Resource).Length), out id))
        {              
            var secondRequest = new RestRequest();
            secondRequest.Resource = locationUrl.Remove(0, string.Format("{0}", client.BaseUrl).Length);
            secondRequest.RootElement = request.RootElement;

            return Execute<T>(secondRequest);
        }
        else        
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not get ID of newly created row");

    }
```